# Движение объекта с помощью PictureBox C#

Tags: c#, picturebox

Помогите, пожалуйста. Задание - нарисовать движующийся поезд.При наложении одного PictureBox над другим PictureBox и при его последующем движении с помощью таймера, рисунок нижнего PictureBox стирается. Как это исправить? 
Вот скрин:

[image: остается белая полоска]

Код:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace Labaratornya_9
{
public partial class Form1 : Form

{   
    private int MaxX = 0;
    private int MinX = 940;
    private int Direct = 1;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.Interval = 20;
        t.Enabled = true;
        t.Tick += (s, o) => { Move(); };
    }

    private void PictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void НарисоватьФонToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        g.Clear(Color.White);
        SolidBrush zemlya = new SolidBrush(Color.OliveDrab);
        SolidBrush nebo = new SolidBrush(Color.DeepSkyBlue);
        SolidBrush oblako = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
        SolidBrush dom = new SolidBrush(Color.Gray);
        Pen contur = new Pen(Color.Black);
        SolidBrush contur2 = new SolidBrush(Color.DarkTurquoise);
        SolidBrush okna = new SolidBrush(Color.Cyan);
        SolidBrush dom2 = new SolidBrush(Color.DarkGoldenrod);
        SolidBrush voda = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
        // Рисует небо
        g.FillRectangle(nebo, 0, 0,1200, 200);
        // Рисует землю
        g.FillRectangle(zemlya, 0, 200, 1200, 400); 
        // Контур
        g.FillRectangle(contur2, 0, 200, 1200, 5);
        // облака
        g.FillEllipse(oblako, 110, 20, 90, 40); 
        g.FillEllipse(oblako, 150, 30, 110, 30);
        g.FillEllipse(oblako, 100, 30, 90, 30);

        g.FillEllipse(oblako, 590, 80, 90, 30);
        g.FillEllipse(oblako, 610, 90, 90, 30);
        g.FillEllipse(oblako, 550, 90, 110, 30);

        g.FillEllipse(oblako, 890, 30, 110, 30);
        g.FillEllipse(oblako, 930, 40, 90, 35);
        g.FillEllipse(oblako, 850, 40, 110, 30);
        // город слева
        g.FillRectangle(dom, 0, 180, 70, 120); 
        g.DrawRectangle(contur, 0, 180, 70, 120);

        for (int i = 10; i <= 60; i += 10)
        {
            for (int j = 10; j <= 100; j += 10)
            {
                g.FillRectangle(okna, 0 + i, 180 +j, 5, 5);
                g.DrawRectangle(contur, 0 + i, 180 + j, 5, 5);
            }
        }

        g.FillRectangle(dom, 50, 160, 70, 120);
        g.DrawRectangle(contur, 50, 160, 70, 120);

        for (int i = 10; i <= 60; i += 10)
        {
            for (int j = 10; j <= 100; j += 10)
            {
                g.FillRectangle(okna, 50 + i, 160 + j, 5, 5);
                g.DrawRectangle(contur, 50 + i, 160 + j, 5, 5);
            }
        }

        g.FillRectangle(dom, 30, 210, 70, 120);
        g.DrawRectangle(contur, 30, 210, 70, 120);

        for (int i = 10; i <= 60; i += 10)
        {
            for (int j = 10; j <= 100; j += 10)
            {
                g.FillRectangle(okna, 30 + i, 210 + j, 5, 5);
                g.DrawRectangle(contur, 30 + i, 210 + j, 5, 5);
            }
        }
        //Город справа
        g.FillRectangle(dom2, 1050, 160, 70, 120);
        g.DrawRectangle(contur, 1050, 160, 70, 120);

        for (int i = 10; i <= 60; i += 10)
        {
            for (int j = 10; j <= 100; j += 10)
            {
                g.FillRectangle(okna, 1050 + i, 160 + j, 5, 5);
                g.DrawRectangle(contur, 1050 + i, 160 + j, 5, 5);
            }
        }

        g.FillRectangle(dom2, 1100, 180, 70, 120);
        g.DrawRectangle(contur, 1100, 180, 70, 120);

        for (int i = 10; i <= 60; i += 10)
        {
            for (int j = 10; j <= 100; j += 10)
            {
                g.FillRectangle(okna, 1100 + i, 180 + j, 5, 5);
                g.DrawRectangle(contur, 1100 + i, 180 + j, 5, 5);
            }
        }

        g.FillRectangle(dom2, 990, 210, 70, 120);
        g.DrawRectangle(contur, 990, 210, 70, 120);

        for (int i = 10; i <= 60; i += 10)
        {
            for (int j = 10; j <= 100; j += 10)
            {
                g.FillRectangle(okna, 990 + i, 210 + j, 5, 5);
                g.DrawRectangle(contur, 990 + i, 210 + j, 5, 5);
            }
        }
        // Озеро
        g.FillEllipse(voda, 590, 280, 110, 30);
        g.FillEllipse(voda, 590, 300, 130, 40);
        g.FillEllipse(voda, 530, 290, 90, 35);
        g.FillEllipse(voda, 650, 290, 110, 30);
        // Рельсы
        g.DrawLine(contur, 0, 400, 1200, 400); 
        g.DrawLine(contur, 0, 410, 1200, 410);
    }

    private void ВыйтиToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }

    private void ПуститьПоездToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = pictureBox2.CreateGraphics();
        g.Clear(Color.Red);
    }
    private void Move()
    {
        var posPB = pictureBox2.Location;

        if (posPB.X < MaxX)
        {
            Direct = 1;
        }
        else if (posPB.X > MinX)
        {
            Direct = -1;
        }

        pictureBox2.Location = new Point(posPB.X + Direct, posPB.Y);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `pictureBox1.Invalidate()`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте в конструкторе формы после `InitializeComponent();` поставить строки

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);
SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
```

А в методе `Move()` в конец добавить

```
Refresh();
```